# Mcollective Does Not Return Hosts Matching Class Filter

Tags: mcollective

Whenever I execute the command

`$ mco service cupsd status --with-class mcollective`

I receive the message:

> No request sent, we did not discover any nodes

However, if I remove the class filter, it returns the status from all my nodes. I checked `/var/lib/puppet/classes.txt` on my hosts and I have the following classes listed:

```
mcollective::defaults
mcollective
mcollective::common
mcollective::common::config
mcollective::server
mcollective::server::install
mcollective::server::config
mcollective::server::service
```

any idea why mcollective cannot find any nodes with my class filter?